# How to combine two objects of different colour with one object completely enclosed in the other, so that only the outer border remains?

Tags: inkscape

I am fairly new to Inkscape and would like to have a shape (hexagon), enclose a double helix PNG (an abstraction in one colour). The fill of the hexagon is a gradient in a different colour.

The helix is placed in the centre of the hexagon.
If I save the result and import it to be used in other images, I am not able to add a border to the hexagon without adding a border to the helix (which seems to be even thicker). I would like to combine them to a single object with only an outer border, so that I can assign a stroke paint and stroke style border to the hexagon.

How can I realise something like that?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  What do you mean by import it?  Import it where? In other software?  And how did you construct it in Inkscape?

Comment: @BillyKerr I meant into a new inkscape document. Until now, I use Inkscape by creating separate images (based on multiple objects, like the one described and similar) and then create separate documents for more complex graphics where I "import" multiple svgs and for example connect them to create a diagram.

Comment: I think I can delete the question since I found the cause of my problem. When importing a created graphic, the elements within in this graphic seem to automatically get grouped. Adding `stroke style`and `stroke paint` to a grouped graphic seem to add it to all components of it. Therefore, ungrouping it, adding the stroke stuff to the hexagon (or a different shape) and then regrouping everything again seems to solve the problem. (Should I just delete the question? - didn't know that imported svgs group all elements and how this affects the behaviour of other adjustments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you have some grouped objects, and you are trying to add a stroke to an individual object/path within the group, but instead you are selecting the group and thus adding a stroke to all the objects/paths within the group.

There's no need to ungroup, then regroup to do what you want.

Instead, use the Nodes Tool <kbd>N</kbd> (the one under the large arrow in the toolbar) to select just one object/path inside the group. Then you can add a stroke to just the selected object/path.

Here's an example. I have two grouped objects shown here, a hexagon and a square. I'm selecting one object only by using the Nodes tool, and adding a stroke to it.

[image]

There are also other ways to navigate around/select things within a group without ungrouping. Here are two options here which may be useful to you.

1. With the Select Tool <kbd>S</kbd>, double click a grouped object to enter inside the group, then you can select individual objects/paths, and apply a stroke.  Double click outside the group to exit the group when you are finished.

**OR**

2. Select the object/path in the Layers & Objects panel <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, and then you can apply a stroke to it.